# How to throw custom exception with empty list instead of null?

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

I'm throwing custom exception inside `Test1` class and passing list to the constructor:

```
    public class Test1 {
        public List<Journal> method1(String str) throws SectionNotFoundException {
        List<Journal> list = new ArrayList<>();
        //...
        else if(...) {
            throw new SectionNotFoundException(list);
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

And it returns me to the line where I'm calling `method1` of `Test1` class inside class `Test2` like:

```
   public class Test2 {
     //...     
     public void method() {
     //...
     Test1 test1 = new Test1();
     try {
         list = test1.method1(text); 
         } catch (SectionNotFoundException e) {
         //...
         }
     }
 }
```

Inside my custom exception which named as `SectionNotFoundException` I want to get empty list instead of `null`:

```
public class SectionNotFoundException extends Throwable {
    List<Journal> journalList;

    public SectionNotFoundException(List<Journal> journalList) {
        this.journalList = journalList;
        emptyArrayList();
    }

    public ArrayList<Object> emptyArrayList() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

But the actual problem is how to write it correctly if return value of `emptyList` is never used.

[image]

Comment: it is not a good practice to use exceptions to abstract some value, like `List<Journal> journalList` here. You can assign an empty list at the place where you catch the exception.

Comment: @invzbl3 by passing an empty list to your constructor?

Comment: @Stultuske I'm throwing an exception in case if my list returns me `null`, but I'm trying to change it inside class of custom exception, as you can see my question.

Comment: @inzvbl, no, you would be overwriting it always. try (in your constructor) something like: this.journalList = journalList == null ? new ArrayList<>() : journalList;

Comment: It makes sense now. Thanks for pointing out, I'll test and correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
public class SectionNotFoundException extends Throwable {
    List<Journal> journalList;

    public SectionNotFoundException(List<Journal> journalList) {
        if(journalList == null) {
            this.journalList = new ArrayList<>();
        } else {
            this.journalList = journalList;
        }
    }
}
```

**Shorthand (as suggested by Stultuske):**

```
public class SectionNotFoundException extends Throwable {
    List<Journal> journalList;

    public SectionNotFoundException(List<Journal> journalList) {
         this.journalList = journalList == null ? new ArrayList<>() : journalList; 
    }
}
```

Comment: why not a simple ternary operator?

Comment: What's the problem with `if...else`?

Comment: readability. and clean code. Especially for something so simple, the ternary operator provides a nice and simple solution that spares you about four lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

To correct a bit myself:

I'm throwing firstly custom exception without passing anything to constructor (as I did wrong before) like:

```
throw new SectionNotFoundException();
```

At the same time, per my requirements, I can write custom exception with method that returns me empty list:

```
public class SectionNotFoundException extends Throwable {    
    public ArrayList<...> emptyArrayList() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

and then I simply forgot to call it somewhere to use this method, so I did it when I catch exactly this exception like:

```
   public class Test2 {
     //...     
     public void method() {
     //...
     Test1 test1 = new Test1();
         try {
            list = test1.method1(text); // generating SectionNotFoundException
         } catch (SectionNotFoundException e) {
            list = e.emptyArrayList(); // assign empty list instead of null by calling emptyArrayList method inside class of custom exception
         }
     }
 }
```

P.s. I know it doesn't quite answer my question, rather, what I wanted to achieve then.